# How do I assign a value to toolStripStatusLabel1 that is in Form1?

Tags: c#-4.0

So I have this code that runs a workerthread and whatnot. I shortened it to show only the necessary parts. In UploaderDoWork I have a text I want toolStripStatusLabel1 to have. How do I assign the value to toolStripStatusLabel1 from there?

```
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions.MediaRss;
using Google.GData.Extensions;
using Google.GData.YouTube;
using Google.YouTube;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows;
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Resources;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Something
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private static BackgroundWorker uploader;

        static void UploaderDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            //How do I assign a value to toolStripStatusLabel1, that is in Form1 from here?
        }

        private void w()
        {
            uploader = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerReportsProgress = true, WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };
            uploader.DoWork += UploaderDoWork;
            uploader.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate { System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ursache + " beendet!"); };
            uploader.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            w();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your ProgressChanged event handler?  That's where it belongs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the Control.Invoke or Control.BeginInvoke methods.  Have a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/757y83z4(v=vs.71).aspx

Something like this:

```
toolStripStatusLabel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            toolStripStatusLabel.Text = "foo";
        });
```

Note that this is untested.

Comment: The name 'toolStripStatusLabel' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Richart - that was for illustrative purposes only.  You should replace that with whatever you have called your toolstripstatuslabel.

Comment: Actually, just checking, toolstripstatuslabel does not have the Invoke method.  In that case just replace the toolstripstatuslabel.invoke with any other control.invoke where control is another label/textbox, etc that is in your form.  Then set the toolstripstatuslabel text as I have shown.

Comment: Now it works. Is there a rate limit to using this? Can I use it every 10ms?

Comment: I'm not sure on its performance, sorry.  My advice would be to try it and see if it noticeably slows down performance.